# I want to draw on the TPanel in C++Builder

Tags: canvas, c++builder, vcl, tpanel

I dynamically add several `TImage` controls to a `TPanel`, and want to draw lines between them, but `TPanel` does not have `Canvas`.  You can draw on a `TPaintBox`, but I cannot use `TImage` smiles on it. Tell me how to get out of this simple situation.

Comment: What do you mean with "TImage smiles"? Do you load some "smileys" into images? Maybe you can do without `TImage`s, paint those "smileys" as bitmaps directly on the `TPaintBox`. Then it's easy to add the lines between.

Comment: I want to use only TImage

Comment: By all means, if that's what you want. Then place them on a form directly and draw your lines on the form canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw on a TPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813693/). Personally, I would do what Tom suggested - use a `TPaintBox` and draw bitmaps and line on it as needed. What is wrong with doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with this issue

```
// before describing the form class in the h-file:
namespace CanvasPanel
{
    class TPanel : public Extctrls::TPanel
    {
    public:
        __property Canvas;
    };
}
#define TPanel CanvasPanel::TPanel
 
// next - the form class, and everything is unchanged...
class TForm1 : public TForm
```

Comment: `#define TPanel CanvasPanel::TPanel` should be replaced with `typedef CanvasPanel::TPanel TPanel;`, or `using TPanel = CanvasPanel::TPanel;` in C++11 onward. Either way, a DFM will not actually instantiate `CanvasPanel::TPanel` objects, though. It may be easier to just let the Form continue using `Extctrls::TPanel` normally, and then you can type-cast a ` Extctrls::TPanel*` to a `CanvasPanel::TPanel*` when you want to access the `Canvas` property, eg: `((CanvasPanel::TPanel*)Panel1)->Canvas->...`.